# declaring variable in a javascript loop every click will assign same value to the declared variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, loading

Declaring variable in a javascript loop every click will assign same value to the declared variable, I want to increment `track_load` with every button click.

```
function loadmore() {

    var track_load = 1; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = 5; //total record group(s)

    if (track_load <= total_groups && loading == false) //there's more data to load
    {
        loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
        $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

        //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
        $.post('autoload_process.php', {
            'group_no': track_load
        }, function(data) {

            $("#results2").append(data); //append received data into the element

            //hide loading image
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

            track_load++; //loaded group increment
            loading = false;

        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

            alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
            loading = false;

        });
    }
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<input type="button" onClick="loadmore()" value="LOAD MORE" class="menu-button">
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed it for you on this occasion.

Comment: declare the variable 'track_load' as global

Comment: @user1921115: "make it global" is almost *never* a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Declaring variable in a javascript loop...

You're not declaring it in the loop.

> I want to increment `track_load` with every button click.

Then move it *out* of the `loadmore` function, into the scope containing the `loadmore` function:

```
var track_load = 1;
function loadmore() {
    // ....
}
```

---

Unfortunately, in your case, that will make it yet another global variable. Instead of using global functions (the global namespace is *really crowded*), wrap your code in a scoping function and hook up your handlers using modern techniques, not `onxyz` attributes:

```js
// This goes in a script tag at the bottom of your HTML, just before
// the closing </body> tag

// Scoping function
(function() {
  $(".load-more").on("click", loadmore);
  
  var track_load = 1;
  function loadmore() {
    $("<p>").text("track_load = " + track_load).appendTo(document.body);
    ++track_load;
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="LOAD MORE" class="menu-button load-more">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @khaldounmasri: Just did.

Comment: var track_load = 1;
var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)
function loadmore() { //code blocks runing here// }

Comment: its now working with global variables, thank you buddy your help is highly appreciated